# Lifespan of JS closure context objects?

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection, closures, v8

### Background

I'm trying to port the elixir's *actor model* language primitives into JS. I came up with a solution (in JS) to emulate the `receive` elixir keyword, using a "receiver" function and a generator.

Here's a simplified implementation and demo to show you the idea.

**APIs**:

```js
type ActorRef: { send(msg: any): void }
type Receiver = (msg: any) => Receiver
/**
 * `spawn` takes a `initializer` and returns an `actorRef`.
 * `initializer` is a factory function that should return a `receiver` function.
 * `receiver` is called to handle `msg` sent through `actorRef.send(msg)`
 */
function spawn(initializer: () => Receiver): ActorRef
```

**Demo**:

```js
function* coroutine(ref) {
  let result
  while (true) {
    const msg = yield result
    result = ref.receive(msg)
  }
}

function spawn(initializer) {
  const ref = {}
  const receiver = initializer()
  ref.receive = receiver
  const gen = coroutine(ref)
  gen.next()

  function send(msg) {
    const ret = gen.next(msg)
    const nextReceiver = ret.value
    ref.receive = nextReceiver
  }

  return { send }
}

function loop(state) {
  console.log('current state', state)
  return function receiver(msg) {
    if (msg.type === 'ADD') {
      return loop(state + msg.value)
    } else {
      console.log('unhandled msg', msg)
      return loop(state)
    }
  }
}

function main() {
  const actor = spawn(() => loop(42))
  actor.send({ type: 'ADD', value: 1 })
  actor.send({ type: 'BLAH', value: 1 })
  actor.send({ type: 'ADD', value: 1 })
  return actor
}

window.actor = main()
```

### Concern

Above model works. However I'm a bit concern about the performance impact of this approach, I'm not clear about the memory impact of all the closure contexts it creates.

```js
function loop(state) {
  console.log('current state', state) // <--- `state` in a closure context  <─┐    <─────┐
  return function receiver(msg) {     // ---> `receiver` closure reference  ──┘          │
    if (msg.type === 'ADD') {                                                            │
      return loop(state + msg.value)  // ---> create another context that link to this one???
    } else {
      console.log('unhandled msg', msg)
      return loop(state)
    }
  }
}
```

`loop` is the "initializer" that returns a "receiver". In order to maintain a internal state, I keep it (`state` variable) inside the closure context of the "receiver" function.

When receive a message, the *current receiver* can modifies the internal state, and pass it to `loop` and recursively create a *new receiver* to replace current one.

Apparently the new receiver also has a new closure context that keeps the new state. This process seems to me **may** create a deep chain of linked context objects that prevents GC?

I know that context objects referenced by closure **could** be linked under some circumstance. And if they're linked, they are obviously not released before the inner-most closure is released. According to [this article](https://mrale.ph/blog/2012/09/23/grokking-v8-closures-for-fun.html) V8 optimization is very conservative on this regard, the picture doesn't look pretty.

### Questions

I'd be very grateful if someone can answer these questions:

1. Does the `loop` example creates deeply linked context objects?
2. What does the lifespan of context object look like in this example?
3. If current example does not, can this `receiver` creates `receiver` mechanism ends up creating deeply linked context objects under other situation?
4. If "yes" to question 3, can you please show an example to illustrate such situation?

---

### Follow-Up 1

A follow-up question to @TJCrowder.

> Closures are lexical, so the nesting of them follows the nesting of the source code.

Well said, that's something obvious but I missed

Just wanna confirm my understanding is correct, with an unnecessarily complicated example (pls bear with me).

These two are logically equivalent:

```js
// global context here

function loop_simple(state) {
  return msg => {
    return loop_simple(state + msg.value)
  }
}

// Notations:
// `c` for context, `s` for state, `r` for receiver.
function loop_trouble(s0) { // c0 : { s0 }
  // return r0
  return msg => {   // c1 : { s1, gibberish } -> c0
    const s1 = s0 + msg.value
    const gibberish = "foobar"
    // return r1
    return msg => { // c2 : { s2 } -> c1 -> c0
      const s2 = s1 + msg.value
      // return r2
      return msg => {
        console.log(gibberish)
        // c3 is not created, since there's no closure
        const s3 = s2 + msg.value
        return loop_trouble(s3)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However the memory impact is totally different.

1. step into `loop_trouble`, `c0` is created holding `s0`; returns `r0 -> c0`.
2. step into `r0`, `c1` is created, holding `s1` and `gibberish`, returns `r1 -> c1`.
3. step into `r1`, `c2` is created, holding `s2`, returns `r2 -> c2`

I believe in the above case, when `r2` (the inner most arrow function) is used as the "current receiver", it's actually not just `r2 -> c2`, but `r2 -> c2 -> c1 -> c0`, all three context objects are kept (Correct me if I'm already wrong here).

Question: which case is true?

1. All three context objects are kept simply because of the `gibberish` variable that I deliberately put in there.
2. Or they're kept even if I remove `gibberish`. In other word, the dependency of `s1 = s0 + msg.value` is enough to link `c1 -> c0`.

---

### Follow-Up 2

So environment record as a "container" is always retained, as of what "content" is included in the container might vary across engines, right?

A very naive unoptimized approach could be blindly include into the "content" all local variables, plus `arguments` and `this`, since the spec didn't say anything about optimization.

A smarter approach could be peek into the nest function and check what exactly is needed, then decide what to include into content. This is referred as "promotion" in the [article I linked](https://mrale.ph/blog/2012/09/23/grokking-v8-closures-for-fun.html), but that piece of info dates back to 2013 and I'm afraid it might be outdated.

By any chance, do you have more up-to-date information on this topic to share? I'm particularly interested in how V8 implements such strategy, cus my current work heavily relies on electron runtime.

Comment: P.S. I promise to give a 500 bounty to whomever provides useful information. Currently I cannot start one yet.

Comment: Is the answer below not useful?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes it is! Thanks a lot! I'm busy writing a follow-up question to you, bear with me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note: This answer assumes you're using [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode). Your snippet doesn't. I recommend **always** using strict mode, by using ECMAScript modules (which are automatically in strict mode) or putting `"use strict";` at the top of your code files. (I'd have to think more about `arguments.callee.caller` and other such monstrosities if you wanted to use loose mode, and I haven't below.)

> 1. Does the loop example creates deeply linked context objects?

Not deeply, no. The inner calls to `loop` don't link the contexts those calls create to the context where the call to them was made. What matters is where the function `loop` was created, not where it was called from. If I do:

```
const r1 = loop(1);
const r2 = r1({type: "ADD", value: 2});
```

That creates two functions, each of which closes over the context in which it was created. That context is the call to `loop`. That call context links to the context where `loop` is declared — global context in your snippet. The contexts for the two calls to `loop` don't link to each other.

> 2. What does the lifespan of context object look like in this example?

Each of them is retained as long as the receiver function referring to it is retained (at least in specification terms). When the receiver function no longer has any references, it and the context are both eligible for GC. In my example above, `r1` doesn't retain `r2`, and `r2` doesn't retain `r1`.

> 3. If current example does not, can this receiver creates receiver mechanism ends up creating deeply linked context objects under other situation?

It's hard to rule *everything* out, but I wouldn't think so. Closures are lexical, so the nesting of them follows the nesting of the source code.

> 4. If "yes" to question 3, can you please show an example to illustrate such situation?

N/A

---

Note: In the above I've used "context" the same way you did in the question, but it's probably worth noting that what's retained is the [*environment record*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-environment-records), which is part of the execution context created by a call to a function. The execution context isn't retained by the closure, the environment record is. But the distinction is a very minor one, I mention it only because if you're delving into the spec, you'll see that distinction.

---

Re your Follow-Up 1:

> c3 is not created, since there's no closure

`c3` is created, it's just that it isn't retained after the end of the call, because nothing closes over it.

> Question: which case is true?

Neither. All three contexts (`c0`, `c1`, and `c2`) are kept (at least in specification terms) regardless of whether there's a `gibberish` variable or an `s0` parameter or `s1` variable, etc. A context doesn't have to have parameters or variables or any other bindings in order to exist. Consider:

```
// ge = global environment record

function f1() {
    // Environment record for each call to f1: e1(n) -> ge
    return function f2() {
        // Environment record for each call to f2: e2(n) -> e1(n) -> ge
        return function f3() {
            // Environment record for each call to f3: e3(n) -> e2(n) -> e1(n) -> ge
        };
    };
}

const f = f1()();
```

Even though `e1(n)`, `e2(n)`, and `e3(n)` have no parameters or variables, they still exist (and in the above they'll have at least two bindings, one for `arguments` and one for `this`, since those aren't arrow functions). In the code above `e1(n)` and `e2(n)` are both retained as long as `f` continues to refer to the `f3` function created by `f1()()`.

At least, that's how the specification defines it. In theory those environment records could be optimized away, but that's a detail of the JavaScript engine implementation. V8 did some closure optimization at one stage but backed off most of it because (as I understand it) it cost more in execution time than it made up for in memory reduction. <s>But even when they were optimizing, I think it was the *contents* of the environment records they optimized (removing unused bindings, that sort of thing), not whether they continued to exist.</s> *See below, I found a blog post from 2018 indicating that they* do *leave them out entirely sometimes.*

---

Re Follow-Up 2:

> So environment record as a "container" is always retained...

In specification terms, yes; that isn't necessarily what engines literally do.

> ...as of what "content" is included in the container might vary across engines, right?

Right, all the spec dictates is behavior, not how you achieve it. From the section on [environment records](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-environment-records) linked above:

> Environment Records are purely specification mechanisms and need not correspond to any specific artefact of an ECMAScript implementation.

> ...but that piece of info dates back to 2013 and I'm afraid it might be outdated.

I think so, yes, not least because V8 has [changed engines entirely](https://v8.dev/blog/launching-ignition-and-turbofan) since then, replacing Full-codegen and Crankshaft with Ignition and TurboFan.

> By any chance, do you have more up-to-date information on this topic to share?

Not really, but I did find [this V8 blog post from 2018](https://v8.dev/blog/v8-release-71) which says they do "elide" context allocation in some cases. So there is definitely some optimization that goes on.

Comment: @TJCrowder Hey I post the follow-up question. Would you kindly have a look?

Comment: @hackape - I've added to the end of the above to answer the follow-up. Happy coding!

Comment: Very informative answer! And here comes follow-up 2 please take a look. Thanks for your time and sorry for squeezing your brain. If nothing to add it's OK. I'll give you the bounty when available. Currently SO doesn't allow me.

Comment: @hackape - Updated again. :-) Don't worry about the bounty (unless you've already put it on the question, but I don't think you have). Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you so much! I know you probably don't need that bounty, but a promise is a promise, I need to honor it for my own sake. Happy coding :-D