# How are pointers referenced in JS?

Tags: javascript

I found this code while doing a random task, and I'm wondering how it works with the memory in JS.

There are obviously more that one level of nested functions, which reference variables from all sorts of levels above (outer contexts). Specifically the variable `i`.

```
!function () {
    function valOrDef(val, def) {
        var _val, _def = typeof def === 'undefined' ? 0 : def;
        if (typeof val !== 'undefined' && typeof val !== null) _val = parseFloat(val, 10);
        return !isNaN(_val) ? _val : _def;
    }
    function reg(els,l) {
        if (!els || !(l = els.length)) return;
        function h(el) {
            var p = el.querySelector('button.decrease'),
                i = el.querySelector('input'),
                n = el.querySelector('button.increase');
            var min = valOrDef(i.min, 0), step = valOrDef(i.step, 1);
            function inc(e) { e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation(); i.value = Math.max(min, valOrDef(i.value, 0) + step); fire(); }
            function dec(e) { e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation(); i.value = Math.max(min, valOrDef(i.value, 0) - step); fire(); }
            function chk() { i.value = valOrDef(i.value, min); }
            function fire() { i.dispatchEvent(new Event('change')); }
            p.addEventListener('pointerup', dec, true);
            n.addEventListener('pointerup', inc, true);
            i.addEventListener('change', chk, false);
        }
        while (l--) h(els[l]);
    }
    reg(document.querySelectorAll('.single-inc-dec'));
}();
```

So, I'm wondering, is that a wasting memory, because each callback has it's own "environment" with it's own pointers?

I think it will be more efficent to have the methods in an outer scope, and provide them with arguments. In this case the `inc`, `dec` & `fire` outside the `reg` function, and recieve the `i` as a parameter. So something like this:

```
!function () {
    function valOrDef(val, def) {
        var _val, _def = typeof def === 'undefined' ? 0 : def;
        if (typeof val !== 'undefined' && typeof val !== null) _val = parseFloat(val, 10);
        return !isNaN(_val) ? _val : _def;
    }
    function inc(i) { return function(e) { e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation(); i.value = Math.max(min, valOrDef(i.value, 0) + step); fire(i); } }
    function dec(i) { return function(e) { e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation(); i.value = Math.max(min, valOrDef(i.value, 0) - step); fire(); }
    function fire(i) { i.dispatchEvent(new Event('change')); }
    function reg(els,l) {
        if (!els || !(l = els.length)) return;
        function h(el) {
            var p = el.querySelector('button.decrease'),
                i = el.querySelector('input'),
                n = el.querySelector('button.increase');
            var min = valOrDef(i.min, 0), step = valOrDef(i.step, 1);
            function chk() { i.value = valOrDef(i.value, min); }
            p.addEventListener('pointerup', dec(i), true);
            n.addEventListener('pointerup', inc(i), true);
            i.addEventListener('change', chk, false);
        }
        while (l--) h(els[l]);
    }
    reg(document.querySelectorAll('.single-inc-dec'));
}();
```

I know that this code will still produce a callback-function for each instance of the listeners, just wondering about the mechanics behind this.

Any pointers to what keywords I should be lookign for to read up on this are also welcomed. :)

---

Please don't crusify me over this code. It's not mine. I was just told "The buttons are slow on the iPhone. Fix that", while doing that I found this gem.

Comment: Each function execution gets its own scope. Each call then creates a new one *in a chain*. If you call `fn1`, which creates variable `x`, then calls  `fn2` that variable is not within the `fn2` scope. Trying to access it will walk the scope chain (essentially) up the callstack and find `x` in `fn1`.

Comment: JavaScript is a garbage-collected language, so there's really no idea of pointers in the same sense as C and other lower-level languages. So, if you want to dig deep on JavaScript and how it manages memory, look into  how the garbage collector works. You might look at Google's site about their Developer Tools, which have some great tools for monitoring memory.

Comment: “Closure context” would be the keyword. I asked a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66981885/lifespan-of-js-closure-context-objects) couple days ago, TJCrowder gave an excellent answer. It’s a bit long cus I kept asking him follow-up questions, squeezed out last bit of his good knowledge LOL. It’s an informative read with useful links. Start there.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I understand what you’re saying. But just wanna point out, GC and pointer are not mutually exclusive. Go is a GC lang but it has pointer. JS doesn’t have pointer not because it’s a GC lang, it’s simply a design decision.

Comment: @hackape Yeah, I can see I implied that. Good point, thanks.